# id record pass and field update

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've built a simple two screen Visualforce sequence on an opportunity.
The first Visualforce page is used to upload documents to the opportunity.

This is the second VF page, used to update a field on the opportunity.

```
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Notify Sales" Action="{!saveRating}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" Action="{!cancel}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Rating" columns="1">    
        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Rating__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

The controller should retrieve set the recId property from a URL parameter, use this to execute a SOQL query, and then update the retrieved record. However, the value is not getting pushed to the record and the update is failing. No error message is being generated.

This is the controller code.

```
public class UpdateRating
{
    public Id recId{get;set;}
    public PageReference pr{get;set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController ctrl;
    public opportunity opp;

    public Digilant_UpdateRating(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        ctrl = controller;
        recId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('opportunityid');
        this.opp = [SELECT Id, rating__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: recId];
        System.debug('opportunity is' + opp.id);
    }

    public pageReference saveRating()
    {
        update opp;
        pr = new PageReference('/'+recId);
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One strange thing i can see at your visualforce page is that you are setting the `Rating__c` field of the `opportunity` object instance:

```
{!opportunity.Rating__c}
```

but trying to update another instace named `opp`:

```
update opp;
```

Maybe you will try to set that field on the `opp` object at the page like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!opp.Rating__c}"/>
```

But don't forget to define `opp` first in controller like this:

```
public opportunity opp { get;set; }
```

Comment: {!opp.Rating__c} did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Are both VF pages using the same controller? If they are sharing a controller you should be able to set the reference in the constructor and as long as it stays in context for the second page you should be golden. Not sure how you are redirecting to the second page.